# Retrieving the actual 3D coordinates of a point on a triangle that has been flattened to 2 dimensions

Tags: python, graphics, 3d, coordinate-systems, cartesian

This is a bit of a complicated problem, so I'll do my best to break it down into chunks.

I'm writing a 3D Python library for the sake of learning / fun (as opposed to one that I'd intend for others to use). In the system I've developed, three-dimensional points are generally flattened to the image as follows:

- Increasing the Z index by `width` moves the point halfway to the vanishing point in the center.
- At `Z = 0`, the X and Y values correspond directly to the pixel at X, Y.

(There might be a name for this method, but if there is, I'm not familiar with it.)

In Python:

```
# vx and vy are the vanishing point's coordinates
def flatten_point(width, vx, vy, x, y, z):
    distance = (x - vx, y - vy)
    flat_distance = [d / (1 + float(z) / width) for d in distance]
    return (vx + flat_distance[0], vx + flat_distance[1])
```

At this point, I'm able to create triangles somewhat efficiently by flattening its vertices and using [barycentric coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system_%28mathematics%29#Converting_to_barycentric_coordinates) to find and fill in the pixels that fall between those three points. This works well enough if I don't need to know anything about the actual points on the triangle that those pixels correspond to, but if I want to shade the triangle so that deeper points are drawn darker, I need to know what *unflattened point* on the triangle the pixel corresponds to.

[joriki on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/173727/36265) recommended using the barycentric coordinates as weights to find the original point. This did appear to work for awhile -- and it probably would work if I were using a linear depth system -- but it falls apart when the depths of the triangle's points differ by enough. The triangle appears to approach the greatest depth more quickly than it actually does, as if it were curved backwards.

So, in short: how can I reverse the point flattening function to get the actual 3D point of an arbitrary 2D pixel on a flattened triangle? Alternatively, if there is a better / more efficient way to flatten triangles without losing the depth of each pixel, that would work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the problem lies in your depth values not being linear. Fortunately, the solution is simple, but a little expensive if calculated per pixels.

Using your barycentric coordinates, rather than interpolating the three Z components directly, you need to interpolate their **inverse** and **reinverse** the result. This is called perspective correction.

Example for Z only :

```
def GetInterpolatedZ(triangle, u, v):
    z0 = 1.0 / triangle[0].z
    z1 = 1.0 / triangle[1].z
    z2 = 1.0 / triangle[2].z
    z = z0 + u * (z1-z0) + v * (z2-z0)
    return 1.0/z
```

*With `triangle` a list of three vectors and `u` and `v` the barycentric coordinates for `triangle[1]` and `triangle[2]` respectively.* You will need to remap your Zs before and after the divisions if they are offset.

If you want to interpolate the actual X and Y coordinates, you do something similar. You will need to interpolate x/z and y/z and relinearize the result by multiplying by z.

```
def GetInterpolatedZ(tri, u, v):
    t0 = Vec3(tri[0].x/tri[0].z, tri[0].y/tri[0].z, 1.0/tri[0].z)
    t1 = Vec3(tri[1].x/tri[1].z, tri[1].y/tri[1].z, 1.0/tri[1].z)
    t2 = Vec3(tri[2].x/tri[2].z, tri[2].y/tri[2].z, 1.0/tri[2].z)

    inter = t0 + u * (t1-t0) + v * (t2-t0)
    inter.z = 1.0 / inter.z
    inter.x *= inter.z
    inter.y *= inter.z
    return inter
```

*Again, `tri` is a list of the three vectors and `u, v` are the barycentric coordinates for `tri[1], tri[2]`. `Vec3` is a regular 3 components Euclidean vector type.*

Comment: This looks promising. What Vector library are you using in your second code block?

Comment: None. I invented a type for the purpose of demonstration.

Comment: BTW, it's been quite a while since I programmed low level raster stuff, and this might be off a little. Particularly on how Z is treated. You might only need to Z inverse X and Y and not Z itself. Give me news and I will update the answer if it's wrong.

Comment: I've been trying to get either of these code blocks to work and haven't had much success. In the first one: where is the barycenter involved? If `triangle` contains the 3D points of the triangle and `u` and `v` are the coordinates of the pixel being checked, I don't see how it relates to the barycentric coordinates. Unless I need to do something else with the return value. As for the second block, I'm failing to understand what `inter` represents. It's assigned `t0 + u ...` in one line and then given attributes `x`, `y`, and `z` in the following lines?

Comment: Both of the code blocks also throw zero division errors upon any instances of `Z=0`, which should really be the simplest case seeing as it's a direct mapping of `X` and `Y` to the corresponding pixel in the output.

Comment: `u` and `v` are the barycentric coordinates for `tri[1]` and `tri[2]` respectively, 1-u-v being the barycentric coordinate for `tri[0]`. The `triangle` is a table of three vectors. `inter` is the interpolated vector. `t0 + u *...` are vector operations.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14367/discussion-between-coincoin-and-fraxtil)